# Android WebView does not load a page without attaching to xml

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I need to load dynamic generated pages in the background and then get the result html. I would use WebView for this, but it does not work wihout attaching to xml layout.
This sample does not work:

```
val browser = WebView(this)
browser.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
browser.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
browser.settings.blockNetworkImage = false
browser.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
browser.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
browser.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
browser.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
       override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
           Log.e("page", "finished")
           val javascript = "javascript:window.JSBridge.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');"
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                browser.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null)
           } else {
                browser.loadUrl(javascript)
           }
        }
    }
browser.loadUrl("https://github.com")
```

But this works:

```
val browser = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.browser)
browser.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
browser.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
browser.settings.blockNetworkImage = false
browser.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
browser.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
browser.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
browser.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
       override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
           Log.e("page", "finished")
           val javascript = "javascript:window.JSBridge.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');"
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                browser.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null)
           } else {
                browser.loadUrl(javascript)
           }
        }
    }
browser.loadUrl("https://github.com")
```

So, is there any way to load pages by WebView without attaching to xml layout file?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, I have to create WebView in the Application class, using application context and then use it as a singleton. This solves the problem.